# ¿Cómo puedo restringir a una única sesión un usuario?

Tags: php

Buenas tardes, cómo puedo lograr en un aplicación web que he desarrollado que cuando un usuario se identifique (login) con su respectivo usuario no pueda iniciar una nueva sesión desde otro equipo o sitio diferente utilizando utilizando la dirección MAC de mi PC junto con PHP.

Alguién que me ayude o me diga que puedo buscar para lograr esto.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maneja una bandera para saber si estas autenticado en el sistema. Si la bandera esta activa, informes que actualmente la cuenta esta abierta desde otro punto y no puede dar acceso.

Antes de esto deberás verificar que la session del usuario no existe, para que no realice la verificación de credenciales.

Al finalizar la session del usuario, se debe bajar la bandera.

Otra cosa que deberás tener en cuenta es, es almacenar una variable que te permita saber cuando fue la ultima interacción del usuario con el sistema, esto te va a permitir saber si ha pasado mucho tiempo desde la ultima petición, si ha pasado mucho tiempo se debe desbloquear la bandera y permitir validación de credenciales y así no bloquear la cuenta(es normal que el usuario, apague el terminal, sin hacer el proceso de salida del sistema, esto generaría un bloqueo de la cuenta)

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar una comparación de IP para saber si pertenece o no con esto:

```
$ip= $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
```

Crea una tabla en tu BD con IP, ingresas este campo y luego en la session le das una comparativa.

```
if($ip !== $ipBD){
  header("Location: http://index.php");
  }else{
  header("Location: http://home.php");
}
```

Espero te sea de ayuda, saludos!